# Spring MVC - Form submit without binding object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im new to Spring MVC and trying to achive something that seems really simple. However i cannot get it to work or find any relevant examples.

Using Spring MCV 3.1 with annotations. I have a form with only one select-list in it. 
When this form is submitted, i want to be able to have the id of the select-value submitted to my controller. Thats it!

I dont want to wrap this value in a Binding object, i'd just like to send it to the controller, preferably by get like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/admin/products?marketId=id

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getProducts(@RequestParam("marketId") String marketId) {

    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();

    // Logic to find products by marketId is not shown
    // ...

    model.addAttribute("products", products);

    return new ModelAndView("products", model);
}
```

I have not been able to create a jsp that compiles yet, but this is my latest jsp snippet:

```
<form:form method="GET" action="/admin/products.htms" methodParam="marketId" >
    <form:select path="marketId" items="${marketList}" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
</form:form>
```

If anyone could help or point out some relevant examples i would be very grateful! I have looked at a lot of examples using a binding object to wrap the form-data, but as you can see im looking for something a bit simpler.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need features such as object binding and error reporting, you can use plain HTML form instead of `<form:form>`:

```
<form method="GET" action="/admin/products.htms">
    <select name="marketId" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <c:forEach var = "item" items="${marketList}">
            <option value = "${item}">${item}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah! Ofcourse. Why did I forget plain old html... I just wanted to be fancy and use the spring-tags.